# "Превратить" VARCHAR в числовой формат в SQL-запросе не меняя структуру таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Беру на PHP данные с таблицы MySQL в порядке убывания значений одного из полей например:

```
ORDER BY my_column DESC
```

В колонке `my_column` хранятся числа, но она имеет тип `varchar(2500)`. Поэтому для значений с 1 по 9 все сортируется как надо, а если значение больше 9 тогда все записи со значением например 10, 11 и дальше т.е. которые начинаются с 1 ставит последними (...3, 2, 1, 10, 11), хотя они должны быть первыми (11, 10, 9, 8, 7...). Насколько понимаю при varchar сравнивается лишь первая цифра. Можно ли как то сделать чтобы это поле "превратилось" в числовой формат в самом SQL-запросе не меняя при этом структуру таблицы т.е не меняя тип поля с varchar(2500) на какой то другой чтобы таким образом порядок сортировки работал как надо?

Comment: varchar это строка и сравнивается она как строка, надо число либо cast сделать либо добавить к строке допустим 0 чтобы она преобразовалась в число. Либо писать свой collation

Comment: Если можно чуть подробнее. Например как 0 добавить? В ORDER BY?

Comment: просто: `ORDER BY (my_column+0) DESC`

Comment: А что с вопросом не так?

Answer (score 1):

как то так:

```
CREATE TABLE mnumbers
    (`onenumber` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO mnumbers
    (`onenumber`)
VALUES('10'),('8'),('9'),('1'),('116')
;

  SELECT * FROM mnumbers 
order by
  cast( onenumber as signed)
```

или так

```
      SELECT * FROM mnumbers 
order by
  onenumber+0
```

Comment: Попалось на глаза решил правильный "хак" для такого случая предложить, может кому когда пригодится:
**SELECT * FROM mnumbers ORDER BY LENGTH(onenumber), onenumber;**
Отсортирует как надо
отсортирует